# builtins.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, attributes, python-3.x

File 1:

```
class Rogue():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Rogue"
        Hero.__init__(self.name, None)

'''class Barbarian(Hero):
    Hero.__init__(self, name, bonuses)

class Mage(Hero):
    Hero.__init__(self, "Mage", bonuses)'''


class Hero(Tile):
'''A class representing the hero venturing into the dungeon.
Heroes have the following attributes: a name, a list of items,
hit points, strength, gold, and a viewing radius. Heroes
inherit the visible boolean from Tile.'''

def __init__(self, name, bonuses=(0, 0, 0)):
    '''(Hero, str, list) -> NoneType
    Create a new hero with name name,
    an empty list of items and bonuses to
    hp, strength, gold and radius as specified
    in bonuses'''

    self.name = name
    self.items = []
    #Rogue
    if self.name == "Rogue":
        self.hp = 10 + bonuses[0]
        self.strength = 2 + bonuses[1]
        self.radius = 2 + bonuses[2]
    #Barbarian
    elif self.name == "Barbarian":
        self.hp = 12 + bonuses[0]
        self.strength = 3 + bonuses[1]
        self.radius = 1 + bonuses[2]
    #Mage
    elif self.name == "Mage":
        self.hp = 8 + bonuses[0]
        self.strength = 2 + bonuses[1]
        self.radius = 3 + bonuses[2]

    Tile.__init__(self, True)
```

---

File 2:

```
class GameScreen:
    '''Display the current state of a game in a text-based format.
    This class is fully implemented and needs no
    additional work from students.'''

def initialize_game(self):
    '''(GameScreen) -> NoneType
    Initialize new game with new user-selected hero class
    and starting room files.'''

    hero = None
    while hero is None:
        c = input("Select hero type:\n(R)ogue (M)age (B)arbarian\n")
        c = c.lower()
        if c == 'r':
            hero = Rogue()
        elif c == 'm':
            hero = Mage()
        elif c == 'b':
            hero = Barbarian()

    self.game = Game("rooms/startroom", hero)
```

There are multiple different files, but these are the only pieces that matter. The code above asks for an input and then calls a hero class based on the input. The class is the part I MUST create. I created a class Rogue where I call Hero with specific parameters. I get the following error:

```
File "/Users//Documents/CSC148/Assignment 2/hero.py", line 7, in __init__
Hero.__init__(self.name, None)
  File "/Users//Documents/CSC148/Assignment 2/hero.py", line 30, in __init__
self.name = name
builtins.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I'm not changing the string, I'm just checking if it's there. Why is it telling me that string has no attribute name for a simple 'self.name' constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening when you do

```
Hero.__init__(self.name, None)
```

is that 'self' parameter is not passed implicitly as first argument. So in this case you actually pass a string (self.name) as first argument (instead of self) and None instead of the 'name' parameter. If 'bonuses' wasn't a keyword parameter, this call would yield `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)`

So:
self.name stands for self
None stands for name
and bonuses is initialized to its default (0, 0, 0)

Comment: Thanks, this worked out. I forgot about the first parameter having to be self.

Comment: Quick followup question, so bonuses is a tuple (0, 0, 0) where bonuses[0] is self.hp, bonuses[1] is self.strength and bonuses[2] is self.radius. For the function call, I'm now calling Hero.__init__(self, "Rogue", I DON'T KNOW). I have tried using (0, 0, 0) and {} as my third parameter, but it gives me errors for both. One says that I'm giving one too many parameters, the other says KeyError: 0. None isn't subscriptable and [] is index out of range. What would my third parameter be for something that will become a (0, 0, 0) tuple?

Comment: As I can see, you have 2 options:
Hero.__init__(self, "Rogue")
 or
Hero.__init__(self, "Rogue", (0,0,0))

Both should work. In either case bonuse will be (0,0,0)

Comment: File "/Applications/WingIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 100, in <module>
  File "/Applications/WingIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 25, in initialize_game
builtins.TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (3 given)

                    referring to:         self.game = Game("rooms/startroom", hero)

Comment: Somehow it adds an extra parameter if I make the function call Hero.__init__(self, "Rogue"). If I make the function call Hero.__init__(self, "Rogue", anything) it stops giving this error.

Answer (score 0):

`Hero.__init__` initializes a `Hero` object. To construct a new Hero object, you must call `Hero`. Therefore, in `Rogue.__init__`, the line

```
Hero.__init__(self.name, None)
```

is faulty. You either want to create a new hero object:

```
class Rogue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Rogue"
        self.enemy = Hero(self.name, None)
```

or let `Rogue` be a subclass of `Hero`:

```
class Rogue(Hero):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Rogue", None)
```

Comment: I tried to make it a subclass prior to posting and the error I would get was 

    builtins.NameError: name 'Hero' is not defined

Basically, for each subclass, it is supposed to pass the correct "hero" to the Hero class. So if the input is Rogue, it passes "Rogue" as a parameter to Hero, which I can see the code does.